# Update CSS:before via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to dynamically update the color to a mini triangle above my rectangle.

[image: ![enter image description here]

## CSS

```css
pre:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 5em;
    border: .5rem solid transparent;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom-color: #00ff5c; <<<<<<---------------- hard coded 
}
    
    
pre {
    color: white;
    background-color: #212121; 
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
    white-space: -pre-wrap;
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
 

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;     
}
```

## jQuery

```
$("pre").css("border", "2px solid #c12222");
$("pre:before").css("border-bottom-color", "#c12222");
```

I don't see any effect.

Please suggest

---

## Live Site (please see in mobile)

https://www.bunlongheng.com/norden?code=rithys4k

Comment: a better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333

Comment: All those answers are so confusing :(